# LightIngest to Azure Data Explorer

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-explorer

I am using lightIngest to ingest data from my blob in Azure to Azure Data Explorer. I am having the Storage Blob Data Reader role assignment under my Azure Data Explorer Cluster. I am able to read and list the files, however I couldn't download the blob to ingest it into Azure Data Explorer Database.

This is the error message: **Failure details: Failed to download blob: Access to persistent storage path**

My question is:

1. How do lightingest actually ingesting the data? I couldnt find it from the documentation
2. What roles do I need to overcome the above error? Do I need the Storage Blob Data Contributor role or there is something wrong on my command

Side note: I have database admin permisson on the database in azure data explorer

My command:
 `LightIngest "https://{XXX}.kusto.windows.net;Fed=True" -database:XXX -table:XXX -source:"https://{storage account}.blob.core.windows.net/{container}/{blob path}/{blob path}/{blob path}/{blob path};managed_identity=system" -pattern:"*.parquet" -format:"parquet" -ingestWithManagedIdentity:"system" -connectToStorageWithUserAuth:"PROMPT"`

Answer (score 0):

Answering your questions

1. LightIngest relies on Kusto Managed Tables to ingest data efficiently. When you use LightIngest, it generates Kusto commands to ingest the data into Managed Tables.
2. To troubleshoot the error, chek that you have the permission I mentioned below
   Storage Blob Data Reader
   Storage Blob Data Contributor
   Database Admin Permission
3. I guess its good to use Managed Identity (-ingestWithManagedIdentity:"system").

Try this code I have modified it a bit

```html
LightIngest "https://{cluster}.kusto.windows.net;Fed=True" `
  -database:YourDatabase `
  -table:YourTable `
  -source:"https://{storage account}.blob.core.windows.net/{container}/{blob path}/*.parquet;managed_identity=system" `
  -format:"parquet" `
  -ingestWithManagedIdentity:"system" `
  -connectToStorageWithUserAuth:"PROMPT"
```

If you still face the error I recommend going through the Microsoft doc, ill give u the link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/search/?terms=LightIngest

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/search/?terms=Data%20Explorer%20Storage%20Blob%20Data%20Ingestion

Comment: hi, i try your way but it is not working. Also the source path u provided having some error, it is not listing the data out

Comment: sorry for that try changing the code and I’ll see what wrong too

Comment: changed the code, same issue occur. Failed to download the blob, I am guessing the managed identity system does not kicked in. Do you know how can I check the log record?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to this. Apparently you will need an private managed end point, instead of a managed end point